# LINKED LIST APPEND, Is ther a way to make this function work faster?

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, linked-list

In my program I use a linked list, I would like to be able to go back to the begining of it whenever I want, and to add an element to the end of it.

```c
void append(struct Node** head, int num) 
{
    struct Node *current = **(&head);
    static struct Node *last = NULL;
    static struct Node *start = NULL;
    if (*head != NULL)
    {
        current = *(&last);
        current->next = new Node;
        current->next->data = num;
        current->next->next = NULL;
        current->next->start = start;
        last = current->next;
        return;
    }
    struct Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->data = num;
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;
    start = *head;
    last = *head;
    temp->start = start;
}
```

I made this funcion myself so I imagine that it could be improved preformance whise. Please help :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want a class to represent the list as a whole. head and last make sense for a list, but not for an individual node. Or just use std::list

Comment: While the style looks very much like C, you are using `new` which makes this clearly C++, not C. Please use only the appropriate language tag. Also note that in C++ you should *not* put `struct` before type names in variable declarations.  Why are `last` and `start` declared as `static`?

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel/[std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)? Also remember that a linked list is one of the *worst* performing data structures to use on modern hardware.

Comment: It for my school projct so I can use std::list, could you link me a code for linked list class? :)

Comment: What other data structure would you recommend that meets my requirements?

Comment: I am going to vote to close the question for need of details, because it is not clear for what use case you need to improve the performance. Please explain how and what  code you timed and why you need it to be faster.

Comment: Assuming this is homework, my guess is that the goal is to create a list class. The question doesn't specify if this is to be a single or double linked list. The class should have head (== first) and tail (== last members), and optionally a size (number of nodes). Appending to the end (which std::list calls push_back) doesn't have to scan the list since list.tail is a pointer to the last node in a list.

Comment: For a minimalist list class, a circular single linked list could be used, which would only need a single "member, just a pointer to the last node in a list (or NULL), and last->next would be a pointer to the head. The list functions would create and maintain local copies of head and tail as needed, checking for node == head to see if the "end" of a circular linked list was reached. Unless you can find this alternative with a simple search, using a circular list for homework may make it appear that you had too much outside help.